# Power BI: How to show "*" as a data label if the value is between 1 and 5 (both ends incl.) in a column chart?

Tags: powerbi

Data:

```
Column1     Column2
---------------
apple       10
mango       2
orange      10
pineapple   4
watermelon  15
watermelon  10
```

I have a visual as below:

[image]

**How to show `*` instead of 4 and 2 i.e. value is greater than 0 and less than or equal to 5?**
The reason to have this is to hide personally identifiable information from the visuals.

If I create a new measure as below:

[image: NishDash_1-1676943961226.png]

the `*` doesn't show up. It makes sense that the bars for mango and pineapple are missing. However, I'm expecting `*` to show as a *data label*.

I looked around but can't figure out a way to work this out. Did anyone have a similar issue or know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests "data label" refers to the "data" that's been used to create the visual. So you can't change the label w/o changing the data.

And even if you hide the label, you'll see the numbers in the tooltips anyway.

Comment: If you check the question, the data has been changed in the measure and the measure is used in the visual. Hence the bars are missing for those 2 fruits. The problem is, how to show "*" as a data label.

Comment: I want to keep the data anonymous/unidentified. Why do you find this weird? Anyway, I'm trying what David Bacci has answered.